# how to set system-wide proxy on ubuntu12, so that we can call webservice in code

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

I am new to ubuntu, now i use eclipse 3.7 on ubuntu 12;
In the code i need to call a webservice, but my work environment works behind a proxy, i need to find a way to set system-wide proxy.

Already the proxy in ubuntu system setting and use firefox with option "use system proxy", it is able to call that service, but to call it from code, it failed.

Also i have tried to edit the files individually like /etc/environment, /etc/bash.bashrc to set the proxy but still not work.

Have tried to use the tool provixy, but i am not so sure how to configure it(i do not set the listen-address, as searched on google it will listen all the http request with this setting).

Any one knows how to set the system-wide proxy?(i'd rather not to set proxy on eclipse or code). Any comment will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in `gnome`, in go to `System--->Preferences--->Network Proxy`.

If you need the proxy in the console to, edit your `bashrc`, just add these configuration:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I already tried this method, but from the code i still cannot call the web service.

Comment: I added these three lines(http,https,ftp) in the /etc/bash.bashrc, then reboot and run the code from eclipse, cannot call the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Already use privoxy and iptables to resolve this